# Get Tab of TabPanel by id or itemId

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a TabPanel in my View with Tabs. How can I get the instance of a Tab in this Panel and which property should be set id or itemId?

Thanks

```
openProjectMetaTab: function(project) {
    var tabPanel = this.getTab();
    console.log(tabPanel);
    var mpItemId = 'project-metaTab-' + project.get('id')
    console.log('#'+mpItemId);
    var metaPanel = tabPanel.getComponent(mpItemId);
    console.log(metaPanel);
    if(!metaPanel) {
        tabPanel.add({
            title: project.get('title'),
            closable: true,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'projectMetaForm',
                    itemId: mpItemId,
                },
            ],
        }).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you define your tabs? `Id` should only be used when developing or when you have components in your application that you know only **1** instance of it get created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `itemId` because that way you don't have to worry about global id property conflicts.  Per the documentation:

"Since itemId's are an index to the container's internal MixedCollection, the itemId is scoped locally to the container"

You can then use `Ext.container.Container.getComponent` to get your tabs.

Here is an example from the posters updated question:

```
openProjectMetaTab: function(project) {
    var tabPanel = this.getTab();
    console.log(tabPanel);
    var mpItemId = 'project-metaTab-' + project.get('id')
    console.log('#'+mpItemId);
    var metaPanel = tabPanel.getComponent(mpItemId);
    console.log(metaPanel);
    if(!metaPanel) {
        tabPanel.add({
            title: project.get('title'),
            closable: true,
            xtype: 'projectMetaForm',
            itemId: mpItemId
        }).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it but it doesn't work, what is my mistake? I've added my code above.

Comment: You're giving the form the id and not the actual tab panel which is nested one more level below.

Comment: How To give the id to the tab Panel?

Comment: See my example, you may just be able to not nest it in the first place

Comment: But your Code IS the Same of mine, isn't IT?

Comment: ... no it's not, yours is nesting your projectMetaForm one more panel deep for what seems to me like no reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

```
myTabPanel.getComponent('someItemId');
```